# how to place two submit of two different forms side by side on the same line

Tags: java, html, css

Guys I'm trying to put two buttons from two different forms on the same line.
I tried to put an id on both buttons so that I can manage them in css.
In particular, what I want to do is put the "delete" button next to the "update" button.
This is what I tried to do but it doesn't work because the "delete" button stays under the "update" button.

```js
//First form
<form action="../updatecustdet" method="post">
<pre>
<c:forEach var="customer" items="${listCustomer}">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${customer.id}" />
.
.
.
.
        
<input type="submit" id="up" value="Update" />
</c:forEach>    
</pre>
</form>


//Second form
<form action="../deletefromdetailslist" method="POST">

      <input id="cust" name="customer" type="hidden" value="${customer.id}"/>
      <input type="submit" id="de" value="Delete"/>
      </c:forEach>
</form>
```

```css
#up {
    padding:5px 15px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    display:inline-block;
}

#de {
    padding:5px 15px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    top:-43px;
}
```

Heartfelt thanks to those who will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the buttons from the `form` elements and place both of them below the second form. Also give both forms a unique `id` so that your HTML now matches this:

```
<form id="update" action="../updatecustdet" method="post">
<pre>
<c:forEach var="customer" items="${listCustomer}">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${customer.id}" />
.
.
.
.

</c:forEach>
</pre>
</form>

<form id="delete" action="../deletefromdetailslist" method="POST">

      <input id="cust" name="customer" type="hidden" value="${customer.id}"/>

      </c:forEach>
</form>

<input type="submit" id="up" value="Update" />
<input type="submit" id="de" value="Delete"/>
```

Place the following javascript at the bottom of your `<body>`, otherwise the buttons won't work:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('click', () => document.getElementById('update').submit());
  document.getElementById('de').addEventListener('click', () => document.getElementById('delete').submit());
</script>
```

Use the following javascript if your browser doesn't support ECMA6:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('click', function() {
     document.getElementById('update').submit();
   });

  document.getElementById('de').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('delete').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Your CSS is fine, no changed needed.

Comment: i tried to do this, but the two buttons don't work.
I noticed that it gives me error in jsp on lines: document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('click', () => document.getElementById('update').submit());
  document.getElementById('de').addEventListener('click', () => document.getElementById('delete').submit());
tells me: Syntax error on token ">", delete this token.                                                                    It also gives me error on "(" right after click.                                                                How can I solve?

Comment: I ran the code in a snippet and the buttons work. Is it possible you're using an older browser that doesn't support ECMA6 javascript? I added Javascript that's supported by older browsers. Maybe you can try to run the code with that.

Comment: How do I add javascript as you say? Unfortunately I'm new to programming. I am using eclipse as a work environment

Comment: You can copy the script into your html. Paste it just above the `</body>`.

Comment: yes I did this, only the update button doesn't work, while the delete button works correctly .. Let's do something; at the comment I put the code. See if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks and sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

I may be talking bollocks, but I'm pretty sure form.submit() is part of the HTTP standardized API and as such it's supposed to trigger a single GET/POST/WHATEVER http protocol step.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-9.5

Answer (score 0):

```js
<form id="update" action="../updatecustdet" method="post">
    <pre>
    <c:forEach var="customer" items="${listCustomer}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${customer.id}" />
    .
    .
    .
    .

    </c:forEach>
    </pre>
    </form>

    <form id="delete" action="../deletefromdetailslist" method="POST">
          <c:forEach var="customer" items="${listCustomer}">
          <input id="cust" name="customer" type="hidden" value="${customer.id}"/>
          </c:forEach>
    </form>

    <input type="submit" id="up" value="Update" />
    <input type="submit" id="de" value="Delete"/>

<script>
  document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('click', function() {
     document.getElementById('update').submit();
   });

  document.getElementById('de').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('delete').submit();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell if the button works here: https://djinesse.com/public/alex.html ?

Comment: yes yes now it works, thank you very much. You have been fantastic

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Could you mark my answer as accepted?